# MSFT build, cl, and link with cross-library dependencies

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker

Hierarchy

```
\Folder1
    cpu.h
    cpu.c
    sources
\Folder2
    mem.h
    mem.c
    sources
dirs
```

cpu.h

```
...
#define nope 0
...
int chuckTesta(unsigned int a);
....
```

cpu.c

```
#include <cpu.h>
int chuckTesta(unsigned int a){ ... }
```

mem.c

```
#include <cpu.h> // A
extern int chuckTesta(unsigned int a); // B

cout << nope << endl; // C
cout << chuckTesta(1); // D
```

Is there a way to link cpu.lib to the files within Folder2 and satisfy these requirements?

- Remove line A
- Line C and D still work
- Compiles and links with no warnings (right now I'm either getting unresolved external symbol, or definition errors)

Note: Folder2's sources file only compiles the files within Folder2, and has Folder1 as an include path. Similarly with Folder1. Each create a .lib file, cpu.lib and mem.lib respectively.

I'm using LINK, CL, and building for Windows8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with removing line A is `#define nope 0`.  If you convert the define to a static integer (or add one) in cpu.lib it should work.  Just make sure you link to both cpu.lib and mem.lib in the final executable.

cpu.h

```
...
#define nope 0
static int cpu_nope = nope;
...
int chuckTesta(unsigned int a);
....
```

mem.c

```
extern int chuckTesta(unsigned int a);
extern int cpu_nope;

cout << cpu_nope << endl;
cout << chuckTesta(1);
```